# Unit tests - entity framework

Tags: unit-testing, frameworks, entity

I use NUnitAdapter. I have unit test for my update method:

```
     [Test]
     public void UpdateBuisness()
    {
        var buis = new Buisness()
        {
            Name = "a",
            Id = 4,
            Enabled = true
        };
        _buisnessRepository.Insert(buis);
        buis.Name = "b";
        _buisnessRepository.Update(buis);
        Assert.AreEqual(buis.Name, _buisnesses.Last().Name);
    }
```

Update method:

```
    public void Update(Buisness entity)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

And I get error:

[image]

This is weird, because for my co-workers all works.

My mock:

```
        var mockBuisnessesDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Buisness>>();
        mockBuisnessesDbSet.As<IQueryable<Buisness>>().Setup(m => m.Provider)
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<Buisness>(_buisnesses.Provider));

        mockBuisnessesDbSet.As<IQueryable<Buisness>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(_buisnesses.Expression);
        mockBuisnessesDbSet.As<IQueryable<Buisness>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(_buisnesses.ElementType);

        mockBuisnessesDbSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<Buisness>>()
            .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<Buisness>(_buisnesses.GetEnumerator()));

        mockBuisnessesDbSet.As<IQueryable<Buisness>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(_buisnesses.GetEnumerator());

        mockBuisnessesDbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Buisness>()))
            .Callback((Buisness bis) => _buisnesses = _buisnesses.Concat(new[] { bis }));

        mockBuisnessesDbSet.Setup(x => x.Remove(It.IsAny<Buisness>()))
            .Callback((Buisness bis) => _buisnesses = _buisnesses.Where(x => x.Id != bis.Id));

        _mockContex = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>() { CallBase = true };
        _mockContex.Setup(x => x.Buisnesses).Returns(mockBuisnessesDbSet.Object);

        _buisnessRepository = new BuisnessRepository(_mockContex.Object);
```

I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your code; EF does not think that the database is not in the correct state. Perform an ```update-database``` or use a DbInitializer.

Comment: We use the same database. The database is up to date. This method work in application  but unit test generate error

Comment: Do other unit tests work?

Comment: Yes, only update generate error